# Angular Unit test Cannot read properties of null

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a slider toggle in my page and also a label text. I am writing test cases for that. But Iam getting "cannot read properties of null"

```
<div class="test" *ngIf="checked">
<div class="toggles">
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="checked">Toggle1</mat-slide-toggle>
</div>
</div>
```

**test cases**

```
it('load slide text', ()=> {
component.checked = true;
const togtext = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-slide-toggle') as HTMLElement;
expect(togtext.nativeElement.innerText).toContain('Toggle1');
});
```

Comment: You have typo in your query selector. Remove `[` in `.querySelector('mat-slide-toggle')`

Comment: that was by mistake,,,,still getting same error

Comment: Of course your `checked` variable needs to be true! Set it in your spec like this : `component.checked = true;`

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the fix, when I moved my **if condition** to beforeeach

```
beforeEach(() => {
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [ParagraphComponent],
   imports: [MatSlideToggleModule, FormsModule],
});
 fixture = 
 TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 component.checked = true;

 fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('load slide text', () => {

fixture.detectChanges();
const togtext = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-slide-toggle');

expect(togtext.innerText).
toContain('Toggle1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The type `HTMLElement` doesn't have a property called `nativeElement`. You are already working with the element so you can access the text directly using the property `innerText`.

So in your case try `togtext.innerText`.

Comment: not working..getting null

Answer (score 0):

querySelector will give you the native element you can directly get the inner HTML, and if you import MatSlideToggleModule, FormsModule in your TestBed, then your test should work

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [ParagraphComponent],
    imports: [MatSlideToggleModule, FormsModule],
  });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('load slide text', () => {
  component.checked = true;
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const togtext = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-slide-toggle');
  expect(togtext.innerText).toContain('Toggle1');
});
```

Comment: not working getting null for togtext

Comment: are there any more *ngIf directives before the test class

Comment: no...other than this no if condition is there

Comment: you also need to call fixture.detectChanges(), updated the answer